# Laravel 5. How to use 'sometimes' validation rule in requests?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-validation

I am using Post***Request.php that is located in App\Http\Requests folder. I have a form and I want the city fields only if my user enters his country Pakistan. Otherwise these fields can be blank.

```
    $city1Rule = 'required_without_all:city1,city2,city3|different:city2|different:city3|in:'.implode (",", $cities);

    $city2Rule = 'required_without_all:city1,city2,city3|different:city1|different:city3|in:'.implode (",", $cities);

    $city3Rule = 'required_without_all:city1,city2,city3|different:city2|different:city1|in:'.implode (",", $cities);

    return [
        'country' => 
        'city1' => $city1Rule,
        'city2' => $city2Rule,
        'city3' => $city3Rule,
        'other_rules' => 'other_rules',         
        ];
```

I want this work only in this file. How can I modify it?

Comment: have you tried `required_with:country`?

Comment: I want something like required_with:country if country == Pakistan

Comment: and from documentation, it looks as i need 'sometimes' rule in it. But I do not know how to use it correctly... What is $data variable in documentation...

Comment: what about `required_if:country,Pakistan`

Comment: I asked the same: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28789802/use-sometimes-function-in-laravel-5-request-class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use required_if:

```
required_if:country,Pakistan
```

Comment: This is like a patch instead of a real answer.